# quiver3 examples throwing errors

Tags: matlab, indexing

I have measured the a magnetic field at several points and would like to plot a vector field. I tried to use quiver3, but it didn't work. I then tried to run several examples that other people posted but they all threw errors.

This is the example given in the help documentation:

```
[x,y] = meshgrid(-2:.2:2,-1:.15:1);
z = x .* exp(-x.^2 - y.^2);
[u,v,w] = surfnorm(x,y,z);
quiver3(x,y,z,u,v,w); hold on, surf(x,y,z), hold off
```

When I try to run it, matlab says: `Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.`

Another example posted online was

```
a = [2 3 5]; % your point [x0,y0,z0]
b = [1 1 0]; % your normal vector 
quiver3(a(1), a(2), a(3), b(1), b(2), b(3));
Index exceeds matrix dimensions.
```

Which gives me: `Index exceeds matrix dimensions.`

Another one

```
a = [2 3 5];
b = [1 1 0];
c = a+b;

starts = zeros(3,3);
ends = [a;b;c];

quiver3(starts(:,1), starts(:,2), starts(:,3), ends(:,1), ends(:,2), ends(:,3))
axis equal
```

which gives: `Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.`

Can anyone suggest a reason this is happening? I have no idea what's wrong if Matlab won't even run its own examples from the help file.

Comment: I guess you have accidentally assigned a variable named as `quiver3`; or it could be some other 3rd party scripts that wrongly overloaded this function. Type `whos quiver3` and post any output here?

Comment: You are right, that was the problem:
    `whos quiver3
    Name           Size            Bytes  Class     Attributes
    quiver3      125x6              6000  double`

I deleted the variable and quiver3 started to work. Thank you!